# Trying to generate a naturally hairy plane

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, particles

i am a total amateur so apologies if this is easy.
I am trying to generate a planar surface that is covered with a "spaghetti-like" polymer.  I have tried to use a lower plane and hair emitters (too straight) and have looked at hair dynamics (but this doesnt seem to do much on a planar surface for me).  Any steer in the right direction hugely appreciated

Comment: I suggest adding an image of what you consider a 'spaghetti-like polymer' so people know what you are trying to recreate.

Comment: Hi - sorry, i dont know how to do that on this forum.  In essence, something that looks like long entangled grass emanating from a plane

Comment: Can you post a reference image? It's possible the community can recommend a solution that doesn't involve hair particles at all.

Comment: Hi - sorry, i havent the faintest idea how to do that on here.

Comment: I can more or less get this to work using emissive hairs from a lower plane and hair dynamics but the latter is behaving really weirdly for me.  If i play the animation nothing at all happens until i change the "seed" number at the top either during playback or just before playback.  Not sure if this is a glitch or i am being utterly stupid

Comment: @DireWolf https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post